# How to Get Myself Up to Speed in Building a Java Web App

Tags: java, web-applications

I'm a new developer at a fairly large company and I'm working on a Java Web Application with a senior developer there.

The Web App is built on top of an IBM stack (RAD, DB2, WebSphere) and basically uses JSPs and Servlets. The Web App is an internal tool to be used by employees to manage data coming from Excel files. So, there are lots of database interaction going around like SQL commands.

My question is: I don't know much about JavaEE as a whole and only know a little about JSPs and Servlets and I would like to get myself up to speed so I can understand and contribute to the Web App as fast as I could. What resources (tutorials, links, etc) should I be looking at? Am I supposed to get a book about JavaEE or something that focuses just on JSPs and Servlets?

What I know well that I think is relevant:

- Java SE
- Object Oriented Concepts
- Some JSP & Servlets

I just graduated from college so I don't have a really wide knowledge of frameworks and such yet but I spend a lot of time reading blogs and working on some small programs (not necessarily Java, more Python really.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to the IBM stack, you should familiarize yourself with [Redbooks](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/), the [product Infocenters](http://www.ibm.com/support/publications/us/library/#software) and [developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/). These are the primary sources of information on things specific to IBM software.

The Java EE spec encompasses [quite a lot of technologies](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=244) and it is unlikely that you'll need to know all of them, so I'd identify the parts of the stack that the application is using and concentrate on those (EJB? JPA? JMS? JAX-WS? etc). Since there can be significant differences in technology between Java EE versions, it would be wise to identify the product versions you are using and what specification level they meet. *For example, there's no point reading up on Java EE 6 if you're going to be writing to WAS7 (a Java EE 5 implementation).* Once you know the technologies you're going to be using, you can decide what books to buy.